# Does replacing an "older" Thunderbird profile in a new computer, cause emails to be removed from another computer that is actively using Thunderbird?

Tags: backup, thunderbird, profile

I'm helping a client with configuring a new computer. Meantime, she has been using Thunderbird in another computer (laptop), while she is traveling. I transferred the Thunderbird profile to the new computer, and ran Thunderbird, to sync with her Gmail account (the Gmail is setup in Thunderbird as IMAP). The following day, she is claiming that she has lost a bunch of emails and is assuming that it is from what I'm doing with her new computer.

So since I have installed the Thunderbird profile from the "old" computer, to the new computer, while at the same time, she has been using Thunderbird in another computer (to get her emails), it seems to have removed a bunch of emails in the computer she is currently using. She says these are emails that are from the past (not newer ones that has come in since she started traveling with the other computer).

So the question is:
Does replacing an "older" Thunderbird profile in a new computer, cause emails to be removed from another computer that is actively using Thunderbird (for the same Gmail account, setup as IMAP)?

Comment: Does she use POP3 or IMAP? If IMAP - does she delete messages from the server after read?

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is Gmail, the answer is: it is impossible to delete mails from gmail using an external client.

The email will always be present in the all emails folder, but you have to subscribe to it first.

It is indeed possible that the sync operation marked the emails as deleted, although it shouldn't, but gmail will not delete the emails, but only archive them, and you can get back to them by going to the all-email folder. If the emails are missing there too, then she must have done something special. A sync action will definitely not remove emails from the all-emails folder.

[image]

[image]